# if line[0] =="#" what does this mean.Is it the string character placement?

Tags: python

```
while True:
    line = input("> ")
    if line[0] == "#": # what does line[0] mean
        print("cont") #if [1] or other number equal to other words
        continue    
    if line == "done":
        break
    print("Hello")
print("bye")
```

Also what if the [0] is a different number and == to lets say "abcde”?

Comment: line[0] means first character of the string variable line.

Comment: `if line[0]=="#"` checks if the first character of the variable is "#"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @Christian Sloper and @John Jefferson Bautista in the comments, `line[0] == '#'` checks for whether the first character of the input string from the user equals `'#'`.

First, note that the `input()` function in Python returns the input from the user as a string. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input),

> The function (...) reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

Therefore, `line` will store an input from the user in string format.

Then, `line[0]` simply denotes the first character of that string. This follows immediately from string indexing and slicing in Python.

```
>>> s = 'foobar'
>>> s[0]
'f'
>>> s[1]
'o'
>>> s[3]
'b'
```

Therefore, all `line[0] == '#'` is doing is that it is checking for whether the first character inputted by the user is a `'#'`. If the condition is met, we will see `'cont'` printed on the prompt. We will also be prompted to input a new line of input due to the `continue`.

Answer (score 1):

The number in the square brackets is an index, it'll return the character at that location in the string (or raise an Exception if the index is out of bounds). As just a single number, it will always only return a single character. If you want to return more than one, you can use array slicing: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations

Depending on your use case, str objects have a startswith method that may be more appropriate: line.startswith('#')

If you want to match anywhere in the string, you can use the in operator:

if '#' in line:
  # do stuff